# mediaplayer.pause() not working

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am playing audios in a gridview.I am having  issue that once the audio starts it not pausing or stopping.On clicking on pause button I see the pause image changing to play but still the audio keeps playing.If i click on another item's play button then multiple audio plays.I failed to understand why  `mp.pause()` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `MediaPlayer` for each item of your `GridView`. If you scroll, it will mess up the references to your view and you won't  be able to handle your `MediaPlayer`. You should use only one `MediaPlayer`, like the one you already have declared `mMediaPlayer`. Try using it instead of creating one for each item.

Comment: if i use that then its playing wrong audio when clicking on an item..it plays some other item's audio

Comment: MediaPlayer should be static and initialized in adapter's constructor and the file should be declared final...tht solved my issue